# IntelliJ IDEA console, Unicode print error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, unicode, utf-8

```
class Phone {
   private String name;
   private String tel;
   Phone(String name, String tel) {
      this.name = name;
      this.tel = tel;
   }
   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }
   public String getTel() {
      return tel;
   }
}
public class PhoneBook {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      Phone phone[];
      int i;
      System.out.print("인원수 >> ");
      int num = sc.nextInt();
      phone = new Phone[num];
      for(i=0; i<phone.length; i++) {
         System.out.print("이름과 전화번호(이름과 번호는 빈 칸없이 입력)>>");
         String name = sc.next();
         String tel = sc.next();
         phone[i] = new Phone(name, tel);
      }
      System.out.println("저장되었습니다...");
      while(true) {
         System.out.print("검색할 이름 >>");
         String name = sc.next();
         for(i=0; i<num; i++) {
            if(name.equals(phone[i].getName())) {
               System.out.println(name+"의 번호는 "+phone[i].getTel()+" 입니다.");
               i--;
               break;
            }
         }
         if(name.equals("그만")) break;
         if (i == num) System.out.println(name+"이 없습니다.");
      }
      
      sc.close();
   }
}
```

```
-Xms128m
-Xmx750m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=512m
-XX:+IgnoreUnrecognizedVMOptions
-XX:+UseG1GC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-ea
-Dsun.io.useCanonCaches=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8
-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

I wrote codes that print Hangeul(Korean letter). But when I run it, the console show strange letters instead of Hangeul. For example, If I wrote System.out.println("가");, the console show �� instead of Hanguel.

I did all of I can. I changed File encoding to UFT-8, and added -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 and -Dconsole.encoding=UTF-8 on vmoptions. I also tried restarting IntelliJ IDEA, restarting computer, and reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA, and cleaning caches several times. But nothing is changed. I also tried rebuilding project, but the console showed me java: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: release version 17 is not supported. For reference, I use openjdk-18. And the version of IntelliJ IDEA is 2021.3.3.

+)I tried various codes and all of them didn't show Hangeul. Above codes are alike what I tried first.

Comment: *the console show strange letters* Which console? One in your OS or the one in IntelliJ?

Comment: Can you share the code snippet?

Comment: @g00se The consone in intelliJ.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: @Kevvvvyp That's no meaning. I tried various codes with Hangeul. But all of them show strange letters

Comment: @김다은  The reason we are asking is so that we can attempt to replicate the problem you see. I am able to run `System.out.println("가");` and see `가` in the IDEA console. I am running Java 17 & IntelliJ IDEA 2021.3.3 (Ultimate Edition).

Comment: @Kevvvyp I added the code that is one of many codes I tried

Comment: @g00se I added.

Comment: Unless IntelliJ has its own fonts, it will rely on system installed ones to print to the console. If it either chooses the wrong one or you don't have one with the correct glyphs for those characters, it will have a problem. Of the two, the former is more likely. Make sure thee console font is good for those characters

Comment: @g00se I searched the font what suit at Hangeul. A owner of a blog show font Dotum can print Hangeul. So I chaned font to that. But nothing was changed ;(

Comment: Might be worth checking your input encoding is set to UTF-8 for IntelliJ

Comment: @g00se UTF-8 is right. And I installed Enclipse also, but it ALSO can't show Hangeul. And I installed IntelliJ on my family's computer, it doesn't work too. But my the computer in my university is work well and I also installed IntelliJ there myself. I think it's something seriously wrong....

Comment: Just please confirm that you can see the Hangeul chars that you posted in your code when it's in your editor, i.e. your source code please

Comment: @g00se It means I confirm vmoptions again and again. I added vmoptions. Is there anything wrong?

Comment: I can't really comment as I don't use IntelliJ